# Javascript ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

My javascript code:

```
$(function(){
    function replace(code){
            var textbox = $("textbox[name=textbox]");

            var len = $(textbox).val().length;
            var start = $(textbox)[0].selectionStart;
            var end = $(textbox)[0].selectionEnd;

            var sel = $(textbox).val().substring(start, end);

            var replace = '['+code+']' + sel + '[/'+code+']';

            $(textbox).val($(textbox).val().substring(0,start)
                 + replace + $(textbox).val().substring(end,len);
            );
    }
});
```

This firebug error:

**ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
$(textbox).val() =  $(textbox).val().substring(0,start) + replace +**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at:

```
$(textbox).val($(textbox).val().substring(0,start) + replace +
        $(textbox).val().substring(end,len); //<-- here
        );
```

you have a semi-colon. remove that semi colon.

Comment: worked in this way:

$(textbox).val($(textbox).val().substring(0,start) + replace +
        $(textbox).val().substring(end,len) //<-- here
        );
Thanks kennypu